# BIND9 sends notify for slave zones, but why?

Tags: dns, bind9

Our BIND9 installations (on 141.42.1.11, 2.22, 3.33 and 196.196) are slaves for the zone **vdi.charite.de**:

```
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.082 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: notify from 10.32.32.51#53930: serial 13301424
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.085 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: Transfer started.
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.144 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: transferred serial 13301424
```

And, although all of our internal DNS servers are merely slaves for the vdi zone, we're still seeing NOTIFY from the other slave servers:

```
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.623 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: refused notify from non-master: 141.42.2.22#36708
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.637 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: refused notify from non-master: 141.42.3.33#59869
  29-Dec-2016 14:28:31.639 general: zone vdi.charite.de/IN: refused notify from non-master: 141.42.196.196#37013
```

Why? How can I turn this off?

The zone is defined:

```
   zone "vdi.charite.de"            {type slave; file "vdi.charite.de"; masters { 10.32.32.51; 10.47.120.201; }; };
```

and our options include:

```
   notify yes; // send DNS NOTIFY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is expected behavior, From [BIND 9 Administrator Reference Manual](https://www.isc.org/bind-9-11-arm/):

page 15:

> DNS NOTIFY is a mechanism that allows master servers to notify their
>   slave servers of changes to a zone’s data.

but also

> As a slave zone can also be a master to other slaves, **named**, by
>   default, sends NOTIFY messages for every zone it loads. Specifying
>   **notify master-only**; will cause **named** to only send NOTIFY for master zones that it loads.

and in more detail on page 88:

> **notify**
>
> If **yes** (the default), DNS NOTIFY messages are sent when a zone the
>   server is authoritative for changes, see Section 4.1. The messages are
>   sent to the servers listed in the zone’s NS records (except the master
>   server identified in the SOA MNAME field), and to any servers listed
>   in the **also-notify** option.
>
> If **master-only**, notifies are only sent for master zones.